# How many natural multisets exist with a given sum?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, multisets

Given natural number $n$, how many multisets are there which sum of their elements equals $n$?

There is a recursive function which can give the value in $O(n^2)$, but is there a formula for that?

$f(n,i)$ = answer where minimum elements of multisets are at least $i$.

$f(n,i) = 1$ for $n=0$

$f(n,i) = 0$ for $i>0$

$f(n,i) = f(n,i+1) + f(n-i,i)$ for $ 0 < i \le n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're speaking only of positive integers, then you're talking about partitions of an integer.  There is an extensive literature on this topic.

See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).